# How can I prevent the request going through on a href using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Maybe I'm trying to go about this the wrong way, but I've set my server up to build the pages if requested (if JS is not enabled basically), otherwise I want it to send the requested page and then the JS should override the main navigation to just request and display the contents using jQueries .load function.

I already have a helper function to make the request and display the results, it simply needs a string as input, which is the name of the page. Upon loading the page I have the $.each statement run to set the hrefs up, but upon inspecting the DOM it doesn't seem to show up, I'm not sure why.

```
var $menuAnchors = $("#menu a");
$.each($menuAnchors, function (index, value) {
if (index == 0) {
  $menuAnchors.eq(0).click('home', setCurrentPage);
}
if (index == 1) {
  $menuAnchors.eq(1).click('services', setCurrentPage);
}
if (index == 2) {
  $menuAnchors.eq(2).click('contact', setCurrentPage);
}

})
```

It's reaching within the if statements just fine, so I must be using the .click function wrong, however I've also tried applying it with the .attr function and it does then show up in the dom, but it doesn't seem to work properly. If I manually call the function to change the page it works fine, so I'm assuming at this point that perhaps both of the event triggering methods are working, but maybe it's still sending the request through to the server and I need to stop the event from propigating? If so how would I do that? Can I do it within this if statement, or would I have to modify my evenhandler function? Here is that function btw:

```
var setCurrentPage = function(page) {

//change contents
var $content = $("#content");
$content.empty();
$content.load("/html/ajax/" + page + ".html");

//set menubar class
var $listItems = $("#menu li");
$.each($listItems, function (index, value) {
  $listItems.eq(index).removeAttr("class");
  if (page == "home" && index == 0) {
    $listItems.eq(index).attr("class", "current");
  }
  if (page == "services" && index == 1) {
    $listItems.eq(index).attr("class", "current");
  }
  if (page == "contact" && index == 2) {
    $listItems.eq(index).attr("class", "current");
  }
  })
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a jQuery event is fired, jQuery will pass an `event` object to that method as the first (and only) argument.

The first issue is that your "page" argument of setCurrentPage isn't the href, it's the event object.

So let's go ahead and clean up the function to `var setCurrentPage = function(e) {`
Now, the data you're passing into `click` with the first argument is accessible via `e.data`, so simply change any references of page to `e.data`.

Finally, to make it so the link isn't traveled to, you can call `e.preventDefault()`.

(extra point: `removeClass` can be called on a collection of elements, no need to traverse with `each`. When an event is fired, `this` will refer to the HTML element that the event occurred on so we can force the `current` class with that.).

Final code ends up looking like

```
function setCurrentPage(e) {
    //change contents
    var $content = $("#content");
    $content.empty();
    $content.load("/html/ajax/" + e.data + ".html");
    //set menubar class
    $("#menu li .current").removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: Well that fixes my original problem, but the two lines to change the current link don't work. Trying to figure out why atm..

Comment: Well $("menu li .current") has a length of 0 so it's not returning anything, though this works in the developer console:

--
[18:04:09.577] $("#menu li").eq(1).attr("class")
[18:04:09.582] "current"

So it's there, is that an invalid selector or something?

Comment: Ok, got it working. It was because the class is on a <li> surrounding each <a> tag and not the anchor itself, so I had to go up to the parent for both of those last two calls. Thanks, that really cleaned up that function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, I still feel something like this would be the best approach from a maintenance standpoint, if someone is changing the links they see the pagename parameter right where they're editing the link.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="/" data-pagename="home">Home</a>
    <a href="/about.html" data-pagename="about">About</a>
</div>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    setCurrentPage($(this).data('pagename')))
    return false;
});
```

A side effect of this is that you could completely decouple this approach from the #menu, in my example bellow, anywhere you add data-pagename="something" to a link, that link would instantly use setCurrentPage instead.

```
$('a[data-pagename]').click(function(){
    setCurrentPage($(this).data('pagename')))
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Well that got me halfway there. It's preventing the request, but it doesn't seem to be passing the function argument used to determine the page. Any idea why? Am I using the .click function wrong?

Comment: `return false` has a few other quirks to it, you should use `preventDefault` here. Also, the `href` attr isn't what he wants to load via ajax, I'm assuming it's a no javascript fallback.

Comment: It's true, return false also prevents other events that were bound to the same event being executed, in most cases though there aren't multiple events on elements anyways, and in cases where there are, it often winds up leading to unmaintainable code.

Comment: I just want the execute a function and pass it a string on an onclick event. It seems it's passing it as an object, is there anyway I can use a string without having to create an object to hold it? Oh, and sorry, but yes, I'm not trying to load the links. I have the content of each page in a seperate file which in the html has it's own container, so the idea is to just swap out the contents of the main content container on loading serperate pages.